# How do I catch an error in Flutter (`beacon_broadcast` library)? Conventional methods don't work for this library

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, ibeacon, beacon

I am using a library called [`beacon_broadcast`](https://pub.dev/packages/beacon_broadcast) when I start the beacon broadcast, it outputs an error in the console, but I'm not able to catch it (`try`, `.catchError`, and using `.then` doesn't work).

Console Output:

```
D/BeaconParser( 7318): Parsing beacon layout: blah_blah_blah
D/BluetoothAdapter( 7318): isLeEnabled(): ON
D/BluetoothAdapter( 7318): isLeEnabled(): ON
E/BeaconTransmitter( 7318): Advertisement start failed, code: 2
```

[Error code `2` means advertising slot not available.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61200485/what-does-error-code-2-in-beacon-broadcast-flutter-package-mean)

I do not think that I need to show my source code for this, since this does not seem to be a problem with my code, but rather a question about how to do something under specific circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your try clause fully wraps the portion of code responsible for the error but I suspect that this is not something which you can solve now.

Looking at the library's repository I can see that it needs to handle first the errors that occur in platform-specific code (in this case Android/iOS/Web) and then that concern with Flutter. In particular, the error should propagate from the platform to Flutter to let him handle and eventually raise the exception. Sometimes developers forget these checks and this is why you cannot handle the exception directly from dart.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The `try` fully wraps the portion of code to start advertising (where it gives an error). I'm guessing that the developer forgot to put those checks (maybe)? By "cannot handle the exception directly from dart" do you mean that, *indirectly*, I can? (I'm guessing that because the error is on the console, reading console output may be a solution?)

Comment: Well, you cannot handle it using a try clause in the code that uses that dependency, but you could and I suggest you open a PR where you solve expose this issue and try to fix it or at least open an issue on their repo to let them know that something is not working as supposed.

Comment: @Leonardro Emili, I opened an issue on the repo (https://github.com/pszklarska/beacon_broadcast) since I don't know Kotlin yet (although Iknow Java).

Comment: Nice, you are now taking part in the world open-source! Well done!