# Read output on Flutter "Console" from within Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, io, console, output

I am trying to read the output of the "Console" part from *inside* a Dart Program. How do I do this?

Screenshot of portion of "Console":
[image: Console Screenshot]
(own work)

**Background (copied from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61215429/how-do-i-catch-an-error-in-flutter-beacon-broadcast-library-conventional-me/61216266#61216266) and edited)**

I am using a library called beacon_broadcast when I start the beacon broadcast, it outputs an error in the console, but I'm not able to catch it (`try`, `catchError`, and using `then` doesn't work).

The console outputs the error, so I thought "Why not read the error from the console output?".

(The whole 3+ question chain of questions stems from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61215429/how-do-i-catch-an-error-in-flutter-beacon-broadcast-library-conventional-me/61216266#61216266).)

Comment: I know this is a *very* bad way to figure out an error, but this is an interim solution until [the issue in the repo](https://github.com/pszklarska/beacon_broadcast/issues/12) is resolved.

Comment: Edited to add a screenshot of the "Console", in case anyone didn't understand what "Console" I am talking about (IDEs, Terminals, etc).